# How to make alert popup after another function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert

I have HTML codes like this:

```
<button id="hide" onclick="hide()">Hide</button>
<p id="pb">This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
```

The mission is when I click the button, the paragraph will hide first, then alert() popup later. I have tried many methods and keep googling, but I nothing improve. Here is my initial CS and JS codes:

**CSS:**

```
.hide {
   display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
 var button = document.getElementById("hide");
 var p = document.getElementById("pb"); 
 function hide(){
   p.classList.add("hide");             
   alert("The paragraph gone!");
 }
```

hide() -> alert popup first and then paragraph hide. That is not what I want.
Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: The additional requirement is I am not allowed to use setTimeOut function.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen — Why not?

Comment: i tried in jsfiddle, I could see both statements seems to be executed pretty fast. please check https://jsfiddle.net/uroubvwm/1/

Comment: @AurA — That live demo throws the error *Uncaught TypeError: hide is not a function* when I click the button.

Comment: sry that link did not get updated, here is the updated one https://jsfiddle.net/ynpk16sh/

Comment: @Quentin: well, my teacher said that it is kind of trick.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen — Yes. It's a standard trick for freeing the event loop so it can do other things. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Quentin: Well, I think he wants us to be mad. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @VinayPatil My teacher requests us.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM is changing immediately, but the browser is waiting until it isn't busy running the JavaScript function before repainting the display.

Since the alert blocks everything, it continues to wait until the alert is dismissed.

Move the code inside a `setTimeout` to work around that.

```
p.classList.add("hide");             
setTimeout(alert.bind(null, "The paragraph gone!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hide() {
        $("#pb").hide("slow", function () {
            alert("The paragraph gone!");
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Jquery**  `hide`  event learn [More](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) .Set some time **delay** or **fast**.

**no need to required hide Css**.

```js
  function hide() {
        $("#pb").hide(function () {
            alert("The paragraph gone!");
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hide" onclick="hide()">Hide</button>

<p id="pb">This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, my teacher require me to use plain JS without any library or setTimeOut function

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of setTimeout() to solve this issue. You can first hide your paragraph and use setTimeout with the alert message.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function hide(){
                document.getElementById("pb").style.display = 'none';   
                setTimeout(function(){ alert("The paragraph gone!"); }, 3000);          
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="hide" onclick="hide();">Hide</button>
        <p id="pb">This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, I am not allowed to use setTimeout or jQuery. :(